# Windows 2012 RDP daily cold start

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

I have a Dell 2950 with Esxi 4. On top of that is W2012 installed, which is a bit slow but good enough. It runs a few IIS8 websites without much hassle.

The only big problem I have is that when I connect with a RDP session to the server after a day it takes a really long time to get to the desktop, sometimes 2-3 minutes.

This happens every day when not connected to the server through RDP for about 12 hours. When this happens the IIS8 websites are also unreachable.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ESXi 4 does not support Server 2012. To quote VMware:

> Note: Windows 8 / Windows Server 2012 will not be supported on
>   ESXi/ESX 4.0 or 4.1.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2006859

Edit: Just to clarify, my point is that before you try to go way out of your way to troubleshoot some obscure memory leak problem or whatever it is, make sure that you are running on a supported platform, which you are not. Even if it were technically possible to fix this by going on a journey of deep code analysis and kernel debugging, you're doing something that your software vendors explicitly say is not supported, and that's not the kind of behavior that we should encourage on this site.

Comment: And 5.0 BSODs on install, so I'm kind of impressed he got it to run at all.

Comment: I actually found a solution for that long ago at http://serverfault.com/questions/426544/windows-8-virtualization-gives-bsod-0x0000005d

Comment: I see what you did there, Ryan. You and WesleyDavid swapped Gravatars. Cheeky.

Comment: I upgraded to 5.1 and it seems considerably faster, especially the RDP!

Comment: My work here is done...